# How to increase height of infowindow in google map v3 for small map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a small map of height 215px. How can i increase the height of info window?

Is the height of info window related to height of map?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way of setting the height of the InfoWindow.

The default width of the InfoWindow is `247px`. However setting the `maxWidth` property of the Infowindow (*should be a value above 247px*) so that whenever your content takes more than that width the height would increase. Like in this example- [Example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max).

It may be a better option to go with using an INFOBUBBLE instead of Infowindow, that is customizable.

[INFOBUBBLE](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html)